# Склейка множества спрайтов Unity 2D C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, спрайт, текстура

Есть массив объектов 16x16 из них вытягиваются спрайты и сразу склеиваются в 1 большую текстуру (каждый тайл 16x16 пикселей), но склейка как то не очень хорошо работает. Должно получится (1), но получается (2).
[image: буль]

Код:

```
Texture2D chunkTexture = new Texture2D(chunkSizeInPixels, chunkSizeInPixels);

            for (int tileX = 0; tileX < chunkSize; tileX++)
            {
                for (int tileY = 0; tileY < chunkSize; tileY++)
                {
                    Sprite currentSprite = worldChunks[chunkX, chunkY].worldTiles[tileX, tileY].sprite;

                    for (int pixelX = 0; pixelX < spriteSize; pixelX++)
                    {
                        for (int pixelY = 0; pixelY < spriteSize; pixelY++)
                        {
                            Color spritePixel = currentSprite.texture.GetPixel(pixelX, pixelY);
                            chunkTexture.SetPixel(tileX + pixelX, tileY + pixelY, spritePixel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            chunkTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
            chunkTexture.Apply();
            chunk.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(chunkTexture,
                new Rect(
                0, 0, chunkTexture.width, chunkTexture.height),
                Vector2.zero,
                spriteSize
            );
```

Comment: А не проще, указать у текстуры `Repeat` и создать материал с настроенным тилингом(количеством повторов)?

Comment: Проблема в том что там будут не только повторяющихся спрайты, а еще и другие, ведь карта процедурная.

Comment: `tileX*chunkSize+pixelX`